# NextJS 13.4 App Router Middleware Page Redirect Has No Styles

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js, middleware

I am using the following middleware to create a redirect if the user is not on the sign-in screen. This is just a test case. Eventually, the condition would check for a valid auth session and conditionally redirect.

However, when the redirect completes, the page has no styles.

This is based on the example from the [NextJS documentation example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#example).

```js
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if(req.nextUrl.pathname != '/sign-in') {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/sign-in', req.url))
    }
}
```

Disabling the middleware (commenting it out), I can load `/sign-in` without issues. In the "sources" dev tools tab, I see this.

[image] [image]

Enabling the middleware shows zero styles (using the default tailwind configuration). It also shows a secondary sign-in document (purple icon) that appears to be recognized as a completely different page. The unstyled page does not appear to be reactive.

[image] [image]

I am confused about why this is happening or if there is a better way to create middleware auth-guarding that redirects users to the sign-in page if there is no valid session (or for whatever condition).

Answer (score 9):

Well all it took was me creating this stack overflow question to finally realize the answer myself.

The above redirect path condition was created to avoid a redirect loop during my testing. However, it is flawed because it redirects **EVERY** request to `/sign-in` including the styles.

I'll leave this up in case anyone makes this stupid mistake.

**Redirect Only Specific Paths**

In the event you do want to conditionally redirect from one path to another without screwing up everything, you can follow the [full example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#example) and include the matcher config for the middleware.

```js
export const config = {
    matcher: '/about/:path*',
};
```

However, this limits the capabilities of your entire middleware system to this config.

**Prevent NextJS 13 App Router middleware from running on static files**

If you want to just stop Middleware from running on static files (such as your styles and fonts), you can use this config:

```js
// Stop Middleware running on static files
export const config = { matcher: '/((?!.*\\.).*)' }
```

Comment: At first I found this very helpful (using the regex) then I realized that static images were not included in the matcher. I found this to be a better solution for my case `'/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'`
[NextJS Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher)